# CSP 'self' is failing in various directives

Tags: content-security-policy

I've recently added CSP to my website and started testing it (Report-Only): it looks OK except for some reports I cannot make sense of.
Specifically I am seeing violations for resources that should be allowed by a 'self' directive.

The server is running Express and CSP is served through helmet-csp. I've validated the CSP policy headers with multiple services (e.g. https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com/) and it comes out error-free.
I am using report-uri.com to collect and analyze CSP reports.

This is the helmet-csp setup:

```
app.use(csp({
  directives: {
    'default-src': ["'none'"],
    'object-src': ["'none'"],
    'script-src': ["'self'", (req, res) => `'nonce-${res.locals.nonce}'`],
    'connect-src': ["'self'", (req, _res) => (req.protocol === 'http' ? 'ws://' : 'wss://') + req.get('host')],
    'manifest-src': ["'self'"],
    'worker-src': ["'self'"],
    'style-src': ["'self'"],
    'font-src': ["'self'"],
    'img-src': ["'self'", 'data:'],
    'base-uri': ["'self'"],
    'form-action': ["'self'"],
    'report-uri': '[REMOVED]'
  },
  reportOnly: true
}));
```

This is the resulting CSP header:

```
Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: default-src 'none'; object-src 'none'; script-src 'self' 'nonce-[REMOVED]'; connect-src 'self' wss://MYSUBDOMAIN.MYDOMAIN.it; manifest-src 'self'; worker-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; font-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data:; base-uri 'self'; form-action 'self'; report-uri [REMOVED]
```

These are some example of the reports:

```
{
    "csp-report": {
        "document-uri": "https://MYSUBDOMAIN.MYDOMAIN.it/",
        "effective-directive": "worker-src",
        "original-policy": "default-src 'none'; object-src 'none'; script-src 'self' 'nonce-[removed]'; connect-src 'self' wss://MYSUBDOMAIN.MYDOMAIN.it; manifest-src 'self'; worker-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; font-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data:; base-uri 'self'; form-action 'self'; report-uri [REMOVED]",
        "blocked-uri": "https://MYSUBDOMAIN.MYDOMAIN.it/notification-worker.js",
        "line-number": 1,
        "column-number": 1966,
        "source-file": "https://MYSUBDOMAIN.MYDOMAIN.it/js/index.min.js"
    }
}
```

```
{
    "csp-report": {
        "document-uri": "https://MYSUBDOMAIN.MYDOMAIN.it/results",
        "effective-directive": "img-src",
        "original-policy": "default-src 'none'; object-src 'none'; script-src 'self' 'nonce-[removed]'; connect-src 'self' wss://MYSUBDOMAIN.MYDOMAIN.it; manifest-src 'self'; worker-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; font-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data:; base-uri 'self'; form-action 'self'; report-uri [REMOVED]",
        "blocked-uri": "https://MYSUBDOMAIN.MYDOMAIN.it/img/icon_twitter_black.png",
        "line-number": 82
    }
}
```

```
{
    "csp-report": {
        "document-uri": "https://MYSUBDOMAIN.MYDOMAIN.it/results",
        "effective-directive": "style-src-elem",
        "original-policy": "default-src 'none'; object-src 'none'; script-src 'self' 'nonce-[removed]'; connect-src 'self' wss://MYSUBDOMAIN.MYDOMAIN.it; manifest-src 'self'; worker-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; font-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data:; base-uri 'self'; form-action 'self'; report-uri [REMOVED]",
        "blocked-uri": "https://MYSUBDOMAIN.MYDOMAIN.it/css/results.min.css",
        "line-number": 8
    }
}
```

There are ten or so similar reports (different images and css files, but identical report structure) and they all came from Chrome on Android.

I don't understand why all these reports were sent: in every case the relevant policy included the 'self' keyword.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Is the entire site (and all resources) on the same SUBdomain?

Comment: Yes, everything is on the same subdomain

Comment: May that be and old CSP configuration returned by a cached HTML document, perhaps?